# List all the peers, part of the channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I created a channel in hyperledger fabric, and joined 7 peers to it. i did all this using CLI container. I need to know is there any command to list all the peers which are connected to a particular channel.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API / command available to list all the peers which have joined a channel.  There is an API on the peer to list all the channels the peer has joined.

There are plans to have a discovery service in a future release which would allow you to discover peers which have joined a channel across organizations (although it would be based on each peer exposing it's endpoint via gossip).

Comment: I have the same requirement, I can find the peers if I have configured the channel in yaml file. what if I have another channel that I have not added to yaml?

Comment: You might want to check out the service discovery feature which has actually been implemented:   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-overview.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using service discovery to find peers. using anchor peer. I'll try to find out about using channels.

Comment: Oh ... sorry ... there is an API on the peer to find the channels it has joined as well.
Via the CLI:  `peer channel list`
Via Node SDK:  https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Client.html#queryChannels__anchor

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I am using java sdk. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to create a channel object unless I manually add it to yaml file. What I want is to create a channel object for channels which is not configured in yaml file and use that channel object to find the peers.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/release-1.4/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/HFClient.java#L559  ?  It allows you to get the list of channels a peer has joined.

Comment: yes, I have. I am able to use that when I have channel configuration in yaml file and load that channel using `hfClient.loadChannelFromConfig(channelName, networkConfig);`. So it's not working for channels that is not in config. I have figured other way around it for now. Thank you for the help